# Music player natively supporting .lrc lyrics files

Tags: windows, music

Is there any music player program that supports lyric ([LRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_%28file_format%29)) files painlessly?

I tried [PotPlayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PotPlayer), [KMPlayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KMPlayer), [WMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player) and foobar2000 without success. I know [MiniLyrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiniLyrics) can be used but I am looking for a player with native LRC support.

Answer (score 1):

not entirely native, but [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) might be useful for you. it's a great music player that can be customized with many extensions (or *components*) and [this one](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_uie_lyrics3) can handle .lrc files without problems. you can load the lyrics from your disk or search for them online automatically when playing a song.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently made an [extension for VLC for this purpose](http://eadmaster.altervista.org/pub/index.php?page=lrcview) (it still has some limitations and bugs, but it works).

More alternatives:

- convert your lrc files to srt and view them in the VLC audio visualization window ([lrc2srt script reworked by me here](http://eadmaster.altervista.org/pub/prj/lrc2srt.py)).
- [Winamp+WinLyrics](http://winampheritage.com/plugin/winlyrics/123066) (both discontinued but still good)
- [osdlyrics](https://github.com/osdlyrics/osdlyrics) (Linux-only viewer that supports a lot of players).

Answer (score 1):

Try GOM Audio. It's able to handle .lrc file without any problems.
Here's the link to download it: https://www.gomlab.com/gomaudio-audio-player/

Make sure you have the song and it's .lrc file on the same folder and both have the exact same names.